# Can I use a C/C++ compiler?

Tags: gcc

I shifted to Ubuntu 10.10 now I am facing problem to have C/C++ compiler. What are the possible ways so that I can use C/C++ compiler using all the libraries (like graphic, math, conio, stdlib, etc) as in Microsoft Windows creating executable file?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ubuntu provides the standard [Gnu Compiler Collection](http://gcc.gnu.org) in the repositories.

You can install the Gnu C Compiler [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org) [image: Install gcc] as well as the Gnu C++ compiler [g++](http://gcc.gnu.org) [image: Install g++] with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc g++
```

You'll probably also want to install [libc6-dev](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/) [image: Install libc6-dev] (which includes the C standard library) and [libstdc++6-4.5-dev](http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/) [image: Install libstdc++6-4.5-dev] (which includes the standard C++ libraries).

---

If you're looking for something comparable to Microsoft's Visual C++ compiler, try taking a look at [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com) - specifically [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) [image: Install qtcreator]. It's a full-fledged IDE with a visual form designer, code-editor, and debugger.

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit:**
Now that it's clear what you mean by "perfectly as in Microsoft windows?", then Qt Creator (which I mentioned above) will be perfect for your needs. You won't need to use the console to compile your applications and the Qt framework is easy to learn and use.

There's a great tutorial for getting started with Qt [here](http://www.digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/).

Comment: "Perfectly as in microsoft" tends to mean as i can be able to code a bit deeper using graphics and other libraries. i find it troublesome using from terminal using text editor (gedit).

Comment: @aneal: I've edited my answer.

Comment: thanks. i will try using that one. lets c if this is the one i am searching for .

Answer (score 8):

The below is (1) a simple hello-world program (2) compiled (3) made executable (4) executed. If you don't have the compiler, install gcc and g++ using the [software install gui](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware), or by running this command: `sudo apt-get install gcc g++`

```
jake@daedalus:~/playground$ cat hello.cc 
// 'Hello World!' program 

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
jake@daedalus:~/playground$ g++ hello.cc -o hello
jake@daedalus:~/playground$ chmod +x hello
jake@daedalus:~/playground$ ./hello 
Hello World!
jake@daedalus:~/playground$
```

Answer (score 4):

You could install the c++ compiler via terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

To write your code there a lot of editors like [Gedit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gedit/) (installed by default) or Emacs. If you need an Integrated development environment, you could use [Anjuta](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/anjuta/) for example.

```
sudo apt-get install anjuta anjuta-extras
```

**See:** [How to Compile a C/C++ Program on Ubuntu Linux](http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-a-C/C%2B%2B-Program-in-Ubuntu)

[German list with IDEs](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Entwicklungsumgebungen)

Comment: i wrote 'sudo apt -get install buid-essential' in the terminal. but i get a error:

Comment: sudo : apt : command not found

Comment: Remove the space after 'apt'.

Comment: ok....someting is being installed

Comment: To use only C++, you can only install g++ which is smaller than build-essential

Answer (score 2):

[GNU's gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

It's present in all Linux/Unix distributions.

Usage:

```
gcc hello.c
```

That's the compiler, but if your question is actually directed towards an IDE, then there are a couple I could recommend:

[QtCreator](http://qt.digia.com/Product/Developer-Tools/)

[Anjunta](http://projects.gnome.org/anjuta/)

[Eclipse for C/C++](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/junosr1)

...and the list goes on...

Answer (score 2):

`gcc(GNU Compiler Collection)` is one of the most widely used `C compilers`. `Ubuntu` uses `gcc` and is installed by default when you install it on your system. Type `gcc <filename>` and `g++ filename` on the `terminal` to compile C and C++ programs respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Ubuntu comes with C and C++ compiler. If you have specific requirement for some compiler then you can find and install it. If not available you can install by doing this,

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

As for writing codes, there are different IDEs available. The one that I use is Eclipse IDE for C,C++ developer http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/junor. If you use IDEs then IDEs will take care of compiling program for you through their GUI but you can also build a code from command line as mentioned in detailed over here http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-a-C/C%2B%2B-Program-in-Ubuntu. Eclipse will also make your life easier when it comes to debugging your code.

Regarding your question on how to open My Computer? You will have to tell me which version of ubuntu you are using and which desktop environment?

For battery do this,

right-click on the status bar (generally on top) -> add to pannel
I have added "Indicator applet complete" and then you should have battery indicator.

Comment: well i installed ubuntu 12.o4. its default so must be unity. thats waht i read on the internet.

Comment: also how am i supposed to check the battery charge?

Comment: I have updated answer for battery.

Comment: If you find the answer helpful then I suggest to mark it as correct.

Comment: when i right-click on the top bar nothing happens,,,no drop down menu opens up. on the extreme right there are icons for wifi BT time and settings. when i click on them specific menus for them open up but i cant see anything like "indicator applet complete"

Comment: Give a try to this one, Click on the power button in the top right hand corner select: System Settings... > Power > Show battery status in the menu bar > Change to When battery is charging/in use

Restart, go back to System Settings... > Power a bunch more options are now avaialble.

Comment: i changed the setting to what you said, restarted and then went again to power settings. no new option was available.

Comment: look at this ...it should work http://askubuntu.com/questions/129086/battery-indicator-missing-in-gnome-classic

Answer (score 0):

You can write your program in many ways .

If you like terminal text editors then `vim` and `nano` are there . If you like GUI text editors `gedit` is enough for basic users .

so i hope you know how to write a program . For example with Gedit . you can find it by typing as gedit in your unity dash which can activate by pressing Super key on your keyboard .

after opening it , type your program there and save it where you want .

Actually you should have a package named as build-essential to run your C/C++ programs succesfully . if you not installed it then you can with

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

from your terminal . as you said you are a basic Ubuntu users and of course new to Ubuntu, you can get your terminal by typing as terminal in your Unity dash as i suggested above .

After saving your program to run it you have to follow these intructions to RUN it .

```
 g++ /path/to/file_name.cpp -o <give some name >
./<give some name >
```

.hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into CodeBlocks IDE. its cross platform and should be available in the Ubuntu app store.

[image: example of its UI]