# Is there a built-in c++ compiler in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, battery, c++, compiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use a C/C++ compiler?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30996/can-i-use-a-c-c-compiler)

I just installed Ubuntu on my laptop because my programming professor insisted on it. This is my first time using Ubuntu. So I had some fairly basic questions.

Where do I write the code?  I suppose it would be the terminal that opens by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, but from there how do I compile the code that I have written?

Is there a built in compiler or do I have to install one? Will `g++` be okay for Ubuntu?

Also anything I should know generally which might help? How or where do I check my disk space and files and all that? Also I cant see my battery's status.