# Is there a C/C++ compiler for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, c++, c, compiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use a C/C++ compiler?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30996/can-i-use-a-c-c-compiler)

Is there a good C/C++ compiler out there for Ubuntu? I'm going to be learning C soon and would like to know if I should just use windows for this or if I could use Ubuntu just as well.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/30996/44179