# g++ Installation

Tags: 12.04, g++

I tried installing gpp in my Ubuntu 12.04, but I can't install it.

It reports,

```
sudo apt-get install gpp
[sudo] password for akash:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gpp
```

I tried locating the file gpp by

```
find / -type f -name gpp
```

But it says permission denied in all course.

Comment: It's worth noting that GPP is the GNU Preprocessor; G++ is the name of the GNU C++ compiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a C/C++ compiler?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30996/can-i-use-a-c-c-compiler)

Answer (score 14):

The best way to install all the basic development tools is to do

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Answer (score 3):

The package `gpp` is contained in the universe group of the repository, you need to add it to the software sources either in the graphical tool or editing the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. It should contain the line `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe`.

EDIT: If you want the GNU C++ compiler, the package name is `g++`, and it's in the main section of the repository.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Comment: You might need to run apt-get update first.