# unable to use static variable in c program

Tags: 13.04, kernel, c

I am working on the some system calls.. 
I want to open the file by system call open()

somewhere in my code I used,

```
 static char message[] = "Hello, world";
```

but it is giving the error 
error :- static: command not found

please assist .

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org) for guidance.

Comment: In particular, please tell us how you are *compiling* your code and how you are *running* it. It seems like you're trying to run a C source code file as a script (if that is what you're doing, then [this should help](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30996/can-i-use-a-c-c-compiler)), but it would be hard to give specific advice about what you *should* do without knowing what you *are* doing.