# Which program do I need to use for programming in C in ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

Which program do I need to use for coding in ubuntu? I am 13 and I read in class 6. I need an answer of my standard. I need both the name of it and the link to the website  from where I can download it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a C/C++ compiler?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30996/can-i-use-a-c-c-compiler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to write and to compile any `C` program, what is required (regardless of the platform, so `Ubuntu` is included) is just a text editor to write the code and a `C` compiler to compile the source file(s). A standard `Ubuntu` installation comes by default bundled with both multiple programs to edit text files (for example a GUI-based one is `gedit`) and with `GCC` ([GNU Compiler Collection](https://gcc.gnu.org/)). So in order to write and to compile any `C` program, you won't need to install any additional software.

That being said, installing an IDE is suggested, expecially for use with more complicated projects. Personally I use [Eclipse CDT](https://eclipse.org/cdt/).

Answer (score 2):

you need to have a gcc compiler installed on your box which even comes installed by default as its used to build the OS. To install the latest version of gcc, check the following link:
[how to install gcc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428198/getting-installing-gcc-g-4-9-on-ubuntu)

To compile, simply open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and navigate to the directory where your file is located.

For Example i have this file here:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main(){
   int age;
   printf("How old are you?");
   scanf("%d", &age);
   printf("Your age is %d ", age);
   return 0;
 }
```

save this as say ager.c under the Desktop and open Terminal and compile this program like this

```
 cd ~/Desktop
 gcc -o ager ager.c
```

Produces an object (executable) file called ager as depicked from the -o prefix
Now run the executable like this

```
 ./ager
```

Should print something like this

```
  How old are you?
  23
  Your age is 23
```

To check which gcc version you have in your system, use the following command in your terminal:

```
gcc --version
```

Sorry but am answering from the stack exchange mobile app

Comment: I believe the compiler line should be "gcc -o ager ager.c"

Comment: IMHO this is the best way to learn C programmming, hence upvoted. I took C programming and used Windows Visual Studio, and was miserable thought the course. Second time around, I was writing everything with nano and compiling gcc - learned so much more just from that, and plus man pages.

Comment: Apologies @Scooter, typo, im using the stackexchange mobile app..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are presumably using Ubuntu, you don't need to go to a website to download either a C compiler, or an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)  or [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor). The C compiler (gcc) comes standard and you can install an IDE or text editor via [Ubuntu Software Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center). Ubuntu Software Center has a section for Developer Tools which has a subsection IDEs. You can also search for software in the search box.  I would recommend starting with [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) for an IDE, or [Kate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_%28text_editor%29) or [jEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEdit) if using a source code editor and compiling at the command line.